# Consultar menor valor de venda

Tags: mysql, sql

Como posso obter em linguagem SQL o valor da venda mais baixa e o nome do cliente que efetuou essa venda?

```
create table cliente (
            idCliente int not null, -- não pode ser auto_increment dado que tem idCliente já atribuído no exercício
            nome varchar(255),
            nif varchar(9),
            codPostal varchar(8),
            primary key(idCliente)
        );
    
    create table venda (
        idVenda int not null auto_increment,
        dataVenda timestamp,
        dataPagamento timestamp,
        valorFaturado float,
        idCliente int not null,
        primary key(idVenda),
        constraint FK_idCliente foreign key (idCliente) references cliente (idCliente)
        on delete no action on update no action
    );
```

Comment: Grosso modo ... Select idCliente from venda where valorFaturado = (select min(valorFaturado) from venda)

Comment: @Motta, antes de mais, permita-me que agradeça, no entanto, pretendo que o output seja, o idCliente - Nome Cliente - Valor , obrigada. Coloquei assim: select idCliente, valorFaturado, dataPagamento from venda where valorFaturado = (select min(valorFaturado) from venda);   ...só que o nome do cliente não aparece. :/

Answer (score -1):

```
/*supondo a menor venda geral*/

select cliente.nome, v1.idVenda 
 from cliente
 inner join venda v1 on cliente.idCliente = v1.idVenda
 where valorFaturado = (select min(v2.valorFaturado) 
                        from venda v2);
```