# Como acrescento em minha consulta para sempre mostrar o valor mais atual do dia?

Tags: sql, servidor

```
SELECT [E3TimeStamp]AS DataHora,
[Energia_Diaria] AS MGE,
[Irradiacao_Diaria] AS Irradiacao,([Energia_Diaria]/1200*(1/[Irradiacao_Diaria])*100) as IDGT
    FROM (
        select *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                  PARTITION BY datepart(hour, [E3TimeStamp]),datepart(day,[E3TimeStamp]) ORDER BY [E3TimeStamp] DESC
               ) rn from [Energia]
    ) [Energia]
    WHERE rn=1 and ([E3TimeStamp] >= '2022-06-22 00:00:00' AND [E3TimeStamp]<= '2022-06-27 23:59') AND [Irradiacao_Diaria] > 0 
    ORDER BY [E3TimeStamp] ASC
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda , subselect com MAX ....   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/557067/consultar-menor-valor-de-venda

Answer (score -2):

Se você precisa do valor mais atual do dia e seu processo atualizar mais de uma vez por dia, então sua query precisa ser particionada apenas por dia, considerando o timestamp completo como order by DESC.

Fiz um modelo aqui, porém não consegui testar..

```
SELECT [E3TimeStamp]AS DataHora,
[Energia_Diaria] AS MGE,
[Irradiacao_Diaria] AS Irradiacao,([Energia_Diaria]/1200*(1/[Irradiacao_Diaria])*100) as IDGT
    FROM (
        select *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                  PARTITION BY datepart(day,[E3TimeStamp]) ORDER BY [E3TimeStamp] DESC
               ) rn from [Energia]
    ) [Energia]
    WHERE rn=1 and ([E3TimeStamp] >= '2022-06-22 00:00:00' AND [E3TimeStamp]<= '2022-06-27 23:59') AND [Irradiacao_Diaria] > 0 
    ORDER BY [E3TimeStamp] ASC
```